# Wildfly: Is it possible to disable the no-interface view?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly

The EJB specification introduces with version 3.1 the no-interface view for EJBs. The corresponding section in the specification states that *public* is the only allowed access modifier:

> Only public methods of the bean class (and any super-classes) may be
>   invoked through the no-interface view. Attempted invocations of
>   methods with any other access modifiers via the no-interface view
>   reference must result in a javax.ejb.EJBException.

Now I have a Java EE application that has EJBs with final methods (as it was developed for EJB 3.0). According to the section above this is not allowed for no-interface views. Is it possible to disable the no-interface view?

Comment: That section doesn't say anything about `final` not being allowed. Besides, what do you mean by *disable the no-interface view*?

Comment: On Wildfly I get the following exception if the EJB has a final method: WFLYEE0067: Method does not exist public final void ...

Comment: Business methods of EJBs (all kinds) have never been permitted to be `final`.

Comment: @SteveC Can you give me a pointer to the spec?

Comment: §7.10.4 of the EJB 2.0 spec; §4.9.6 of the EJB 3.1 and EJB 3.2 Specs.

Comment: ...and §4.6.5 of the EJB 3.0 spec since you mentioned this one explicitly

Comment: The error indicates that a method referenced isn't available. Only public methods of the bean class (and any superclasses) may be invoked through the no-interface
view. Attempted invocations of methods with any other access modifiers via the no-interface view reference
must result in the javax.ejb.EJBException.

Comment: When interacting with a reference to the no-interface view, the client must not make any assumptions
regarding the internal implementation of the reference, such as any instance-specific state that may be
present in the reference. Although the reference object is type-compatible with the corresponding bean
class type, there is no prescribed relationship between the internal implementation of the reference and
the implementation of the bean instance.